# Elasticsearch multiple sum aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, nosql

We have **a lot of documents** in each index (~10 000 000). But each document is very small and contains almost only integer values.

We needed to SUM all numerical field.

1. **First step** - We ask for all available fields with a **mapping**.

Example :

```
GET INDEX/TYPE/_mapping
```

2. **Second step** - We build the request with the fields from the mapping.

Example :

```
GET INDEX/TYPE/_search
{
    // SOME FILTERS TO REDUCE THE NUMBER OF DOCUMENTS
    "size":0,
    "aggs":{  
        "FIELD 1":{  
            "sum":{  
                "field":"FIELD 1"
            }
        },
        "FIELD 2":{  
            "sum":{  
                "field":"FIELD 2"
            }
        },
        // ...
        "FIELD N":{  
            "sum":{  
                "field":"FIELD N"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Our problem is that the second request **execution time is linear with the number of field N**.

That's not acceptable as this is **only sums**. So we tried to generate our own aggregation with a **scripted metric (groovy)**.

Exemple with only 2 fields :

```
// ...
"aggs": {
    "test": {
        "scripted_metric": {
            "init_script": "_agg['t'] = []",
            "map_script": "_agg.t.add(doc)",
            "combine_script": "res = [:]; res['FIELD 1'] = 0; res['FIELD 2'] = 0; for (t in _agg.t) { res['FIELD 1'] += t.['FIELD 1']; res['FIELD 2'] += t.['FIELD 2']; }; return res", 
            "reduce_script": "res = [:]; res['FIELD 1'] = 0; res['FIELD 2'] = 0; for (t in _aggs) { res['FIELD 1'] += t.['FIELD 1']; res['FIELD 2'] += t.['FIELD 2']; }; return res"
        }
    }
}
// ...
```

But it appears that the **more affectations we add in the script, the more time it takes to execute it**, so it doesn't solve our problem.

There is not a lot of example out there.

**Do you have some ideas to improve this script performances ? 
Or other ideas ?**

Comment: Scripts are usually costly. I dont see a reason to use scripts here. Cant you use the sum metric aggregation ?

Comment: What do you mean ? We did use sum aggregation over all fields and it's too slow.

Comment: Why are you using script , use this  -https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html

Comment: We use it (look at my question : step 2). But we need to use it over many document fields.

Comment: not sure if this helps but i would try splitting the 1st request into multiple requests each aggregating a subset set of fields. I would then do the multiple requests using bulk request  [_msearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) , you would have to repeat the filters though maybe worth a shot .

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: No, we did not succeed. Our app was using MongoDB and we were trying to move to ES, but it seems that MongoDB is faster for this kind of requests (the number of fields does not impact the performances) so we went back on MongoDB

Answer (score 1):

How could it calculate N sums in sub-linear time, does any such system exist?

10 million document's isn't actually that many. How long are your queries taking, how many shards do you have and is the CPU maxed at 100%? *(I was gonna ask these in a comment but don't have 50 reputation yet)*.

If you are interested in the total sum of all fields you could pre-calculate document-level sums when you are indexing the document and then at query time just take the sum of these values.

You could also try storing fields as [doc_values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/doc-values.html) and see if it helps. You would have less memory pressure and garbage collection, although docs mention a possible 10 - 25% performance hit.